# Suggestions on computing intersection cohomology of a variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $ f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{1}$ be a map with fibre $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ over the $\mathbb{A}^{1}$ stratum and $\mathbb{P}^{2}$ over $\infty$.

I would like to be able to try to compute the intersection cohomology of this and it seems like a simple enough variety that this should be computable but I'm still relatively new to this area and am not managing to get an answer.

Given I am trying to get this to match a polynomial $f(q) = 1 + 2q^{2} + q^{4}$ (which has come from representation theory) I would hope the answer is

\begin{equation} 
dim IC^{i}_{c}(X) = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{ if }i \in \{0,4\} \\ 2, & \text{ if }i = 2 \\ 0, & \text{ otherwise } \end{cases}
\end{equation}

But I would find this very surprising if true.

Is anyone able to give a suggestion on how to compute it or knows the answer and can thus put me out of my misery.
(Also, if this isn't the case am I right in assuming that if $X_{reg}$ is the smooth locus then $\overline{X_{reg}} = \mathbb{P}^{1} \times \mathbb{P}^{1}$? This would give the polynomial above so may be what I'm looking for).

Thanks

Comment: It's very hard to follow this question. What are "the rest of the varieties" you computed, what are "your polynomials" and what do they match?

Comment: I'll try to make this as short a question as possible.

Comment: It's not true that the compactification of your $X$ is $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$. You may get a Hirzebruch surface. But their cohomology is identical.